# Why custom material UI styles not reflecting after deployment?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I was trying to implement a customized material UI element. Here is how I was trying to increase the size of the icon.

Here is my style code:

```
export const Icon = styled(Box)({
    color: "gray",
    position: "relative",

    "& .css-i4bv87-MuiSvgIcon-root": {
        fontSize: "2rem",
    },

    "&:hover": {
        color: "black",
    },
});
```

App.js:

```
<Icon>{icon}</Icon>
```

While development the style is showing properly as intended, but when I have deployed my app I could see that the style

```
"& .css-i4bv87-MuiSvgIcon-root": {
        fontSize: "2rem",
    }
```

is not reflecting in my application.

Can someone guide me?

Comment: You should avoid using the `.css-i4bv87-` since this is added but I changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the thing is that you are using `MuiSvgIcon-root` to add the style but in your `styled(Box)` see that you have a Box. So you need to add style to the correct css class.

If you inspect the css you will see that with your style code the class used is the MuiBox-root:

[image]

I've tried in a react codesanbox with this:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { styled, Box } from "@mui/material";

const Icon = styled(Box)({
  color: "gray",
  position: "relative",

  "&.MuiBox-root": {
    fontSize: "2rem",

    ":hover": {
      color: "black"
    }
  }
});

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <Icon>my icon</Icon>
    </div>
  );
}
```

LINK: https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-zeh-yhgqob?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

Make their precedence higher by making it `important` may be some other class overriding it! Check on inspect after deployed version.